# Undesirable destructor call when starting a thread on a member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have an event loop in my main function, in which I would like to create an object and run a thread on the object's member function. However, I have noticed that the object is destroyed before the thread is even starting. I don't understand why.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(){
        std::cout << "MyClass constructor is called" << std::endl;
    }
    ~MyClass(){
        std::cout << "MyClass destructor is called" << std::endl;
    }    
    void start(){
        std::cout << "MyClass is starting" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
        MyClass mine;
        std::thread t(&MyClass::start, mine);
        t.join();
}
```

Output:

```
MyClass constructor is called
MyClass destructor is called
MyClass is starting
MyClass destructor is called
MyClass destructor is called
```

Desired output:

```
MyClass constructor is called
MyClass is starting
MyClass destructor is called
```

Comment: When logging constructor/destructor, don't forget copy/move constructors (and potentially assignment).

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for the advice. But allow me to respectfully disagree. Aside from the fact that my confusion simply came from a mix-up between pass-by-reference and pass-by-value (and not _the basics of object lifetime_), I'd rather (and have to, due to my job) learn pre-requisits that I'm missing while using more advanced features. Such comments are not the answers that learners, such as myself, are looking for in SO when encountering a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

pass `mine` by reference:  `std::thread t(&MyClass::start, std::ref(mine));`
the type of `mine` is `MyClass`, meaning you pass it by value. so `std::thread` passes a copy of it to the newly created thread.

you need to explicitly tell the template you are passing `mine` by reference.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I can understand that pass-by-reference was what I wanted all along. But I don't understand why the destructor is called before the thread is entering the function. If it's making a copy of the object and is working on that instead, I don't understand why its destructor is being called that early. Could you please clarify on that?

Comment: the thread destroys the copy it holds, and the main destroys the original. this is  why you see 2 destructions. if you put `getchar()` after`t.join()` you will see only one destruction

Comment: @narengi Because you never log the copy copy/move constructors.  You need that to see what is really happening.

Comment: I get that the destructor should be called two times (though it's being called 3 times according to my output ?!). My question is that why "MyClass destructor is called" line is printed before "MyClass is starting" line.

Comment: @NathanOliver I see. I'll do that. Great advice. thanks

Comment: @narengi The constructor of `std::thread` is possibly copying/moving its argument into some kind of internal storage inside the `std::thread` class. So you'd have 3 objects: `mine`, an argument of `std::thread::thread()` (the ctor), and a data member in `std::thread`.

Comment: You can also pass by pointer instead of reference: `std::thread t(&MyClass::start, &mine);`

Answer (score 3):

`std::thread` internally creates local object and call copy constructor multiple times and destroy local object once used. Because of that you are getting more than one output as `MyClass destructor is called`.
if you want to check the behavior of object construction then you can include a copy constructor in your class.